# How to merge my branch to master if some other branch has been merged into the master

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

I'm new to using git with teammates and I don't understand the workflow very well yet.

Let's say master branch is **ABC**.

1. I branch it into dev1 and develop on it and it was now **ABCD**.
2. Someone branch it into dev2 and his final value was **ACCDE**.
3. Then dev2 merged into master and master branch final value is **ACCDE**.

Since dev1 was working on ABC version of master so, how to continue development on dev1 which depends on previous version of master when master value was changed from ABC to ACCDE.

Added info:
I was still working on dev1 so I can't merge dev1 to master yet, and then dev2 which was edited and added with new features was merged into master. The problem is the feature I was working on on dev1 depends on unedited version of master and now the master was changed and I no longer can work on my development on dev1
Thanks

Comment: I wonder what happened with revision B. Does it imply the history of the branch was rewritten? Even more so, why CC?

Comment: Either way, it doesn't matter the order in which branches are merged in. Git will be able to see the differences that are put in by each branch involved in the merge, it doesn't matter their order.

Comment: @efshift0 My intention of changing B to C was to show that the master branch was edited and futhermore added some new features. So my branch was not only missing the new added features but also some codes were changed in the master branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to merge the current version of master into your branch.
You will have to live with those commits eventually, so you might as well merge them into your branch sooner rather than later, to make the merge easier.

Your working branch is dev1.
Here is the process I use.

Get the latest version of master

git checkout master

git pull origin master  (I like to be specific about what I pull. It keeps my head on straight)

Now that your local copy of master is up to date, merge master into your branch. (This is different than merging your branch into master. You only do that when you are completely done with your branch.)

git checkout dev1

git merge master
(If there are conflicts, resolve them as described by Lajos)

If other developers continue to work on master, then you may need to do this periodically. I prefer to merge master into my dev branch frequently so that at the end of developing my branch I don't have a lot of
merge conflicts, which can happen if a lot of development has been done on master.

Comment: At the end of your development you can merge your branch into master so that master has your changes. "git checkout master"   "git merge dev1"  (fix any merge conflicts).  "git push origin master"

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebase your `dev1` branch on `master` (and resolve any potential conflicts).

```
git checkout dev1
git rebase master
```

See [Git Branching - Rebasing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing).

Comment: So can I say that it is a good practice to always rebase the branch before we merge into master.

Comment: @LeeYuan Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Is it good practice? Sure! Is it mandatory? No... and there are situations where it is actually undesired. For instance, one of the things that you might do to send a patch is to start your branch from the oldest possible release version where the patch is applicable, say, if you found a bug. I think it is one of the things they do in git (the project). It is one of the advantages of git: extreme flexibility, you can move stuff around with ease.

Answer (score 0):

You have to merge dev1 into master and resolve conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have three branches:

- master
- branch1
- branch2

There were commits done inside branch1 and branch2. Let's assume that you work on branch2 and branch1 is already merged into master. You could do the following

```
git checkout master
git merge branch2
```

However, you may have conflicts if both branches worked on the same files. If you have such a conflict, then you can run

```
git status
```

in order to see what the conflicting files are. Opening each and every file you will see sections like

```
<<<<<<<
=======
>>>>>>>
```

The first line above signifies the first branch and the last line signifies the end of the last branch. Between the lines you will find the different versions. You will need to figure out which are the correct lines from each and perform modifications until the code works. Finally, remove the lines above along with the content in-between.

However, you may want to avoid solving the conflicts inside master, because that's central and it is better to localize problems in my opinion, so what I actually do, assuming that I'm on branch2:

```
git status
git add myfile1
git add myfile2
git commit
git pull
git push
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout branch2
git merge master
```

If there are conflicts, then solve them and then

```
git checkout master
git merge branch2
```

EDIT:

Apparently there was an earlier version of master which differs from branch2, yet, branch1 would add commits that are not desired at this point. So solve it, first:

```
git checkout master
```

to view what's in master. Then see what the commits into master were via

```
git log
```

You will see a list of commits. Find the newest commit that's still good and you will see its hash, which is a long alphanumeric string. Let's call id  for now, but you will need its actual value. Now switch back to your branch:

```
git checkout branch2
```

and merge that commit into your branch

```
git merge <hash>
```

Comment: I was still working on branch1 so I can't merge branch1 to master yet, and then branch2 which was edited and added with new features was merged into master. The problem is the feature I was working on on branch 1 depends on unedited version of master and now the master was changed and I no longer can work on my development on branch 1.

Comment: Understood. Please read the edit of my answer.